# how do I leave myself a permanent note on my iphone?

Tags: notes.app

OK, this is an incredibly basic question, but I have looked far and wide and cannot find a simple answer anywhere.  I want to record some PERMANENT notes to myself on my IPhone, such as my office hours (which I can never remember), and my family's health insurance ID's.  How can I do this?  I want the least fancy way possible.  My wife is pretty tech-savvy, and the best thing she could think of was to take a photo of a piece of paper with my office hours and save it.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with writing a note in Notes.app and leaving it there? I've had a "permanent note" like this for ~4 years, surviving multiple phone restores/updates and device upgrades.

Comment: If your wife is tech-savvy, she must know something about your situation that we don't. There are many note-taking apps available. A good number with photo-taking capabilities (i.e Evernote) and even transcription. Could you describe a little more of your situation? I'm sure there are tools available to help.

Comment: @roviuser, I used the Notes app, which my wife had hidden in a "Junk" folder (and I couldn't find it until just now).  All I wanted to do was store some simple text.  It has today's date and I'll see if it stays there.  I don't know why my wife was unaware of this simple solution.  By the way, I Googled this question and even looked in a beginner's IPhone book before I posted this and all I could find much fancier than I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably hundreds of note taking, clipping saving, or even drawing apps that could handle the simple task of taking and saving a note "permanently". (Not sure what you mean by that — of course if the device has to be reset, it's not permanent. But you should be backing up your device anyway, and the files will be saved, so this clarification seems strange.)

For potentially sensitive information like health insurance IDs and credit cards etc, I would recommend [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/ios). It has the added bonus, of course, of keeping your passwords and serial numbers easily at hand and synced across devices.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the Notes app.  The note is dated today; Hopefully it stays there.  By "permanent" I mean lasting until I need to do something major like reset the phone.  I don't trust any electronic device for truly sensitive information like credit card numbers or passwords, but I will look into 1Password for semisensitive information such as health insurance ID's.  Why the downvote?  I Googled this question and even looked for answers in beginning IPhone book, and all I found was a lot of fancy crap.

Comment: @StEFAN I did not downvote you; my guess is people found your question too basic and not specific enough: you tagged your post with "notes.app" which is the obvious solution, but didn't specify why it was inadequate.

Comment: @StEFAN As for your trust issues, a healthy dose of caution and skepticism is good, but 1Password's encryption is 128-bit AES which would take millions of years to decrypt with brute force. I would rather have one high-complexity password protecting dozens of other different passwords and credit card numbers instead of using the same password for everything — a security nightmare if compromised. 1Password lets me carry all my sensitive information with me instead of a wallet/notebook which has no security whatsoever.